# angularjs responsive datepicker

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

May be this question is asked lot of time, but I will ask again. I am looking for pure angularjs date picker **without jquery and bootstarp**. It should be responsive as I am going to use for mobile app in ionic framework.

It should max and min date setting and more than 1 time can be use.

`HTML View`

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="item-text-wrap item col col-50">
            <div class="item-icon-left">
                <i class="icon ion-calendar"></i>
                <input type="text" class="dateClass" pick-a-date="depDate" pick-a-date-options="depOptions" placeholder="Departure Date" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-text-wrap item col col-50">
            <div class="item-icon-left">
                <i class="icon ion-calendar"></i>
                <input type="text" class="dateClass" pick-a-date="arrDate" placeholder="Arrival Date" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

`Controller Code`

```
var minDate = new Date();
        var maxDate = new Date(minDate.getFullYear() + 1, minDate.getMonth(), minDate.getDate());
        $scope.depOptions = {
          format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
          min: minDate,
          max: maxDate,
          onClose: function(e) {
            alert($scope.depDate);
          }
        }
```

Now if you see I used `$scope.depDate` in `onClose` method but I always get undefined. Actually I am trying make min date for second directive to be the selected date of first directive.

Comment: Are you looking for a popup calendar style date picker, or a simple set of select lists for month/day/year?

Comment: popup kind just date(no need of time)

Comment: I tested your code and it seems to work, can you try this and see if it has the same problem you're having?  When I click on the first text box, I get the date picker.  When I pick a date the alert box displays the selected date.  http://plnkr.co/edit/Alk40aESETsrJBKLrsfu?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for your effort. But I found the issue. Your plnkr working very good but when add reference ionic.bundle.js it stop working. So it is issue with ionic. I don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one looks promising, doesn't seem to require jquery or bootstrap:

https://github.com/alongubkin/angular-datepicker

Comment: I can't get this working in a modal, ended up going with the html5 "date" input type.

Answer (score 5):

I have create a `ionic-datepicker` bower component. You can use it. No additional dependencies are required.
https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-datepicker

You can even have a look at the `ionic-timepicker` bower component. No additional dependencies are required.
https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-timepicker

Comment: Thanks for nice control. But when i build apk from ionic build android. Date picker does not so dropdown properly and time picker also does not so properly. Can you help for me solving this?

Comment: There are few css classes i have added. You can use them and override accordingly.

Comment: @Rajeshwar Can i use your date picker for only year picker? I already used your date picker. But, i want year picker as well for my project. Please help me if possible.

Comment: No, with the current component you can select day, month and year only.

Comment: @Rajeshwar - I am looking for a DataTime picker. A single component which when value is empty on click should by default put the current date-time in it, without showing nay popup. And if some value is already selected, then I need to show a popup to allow user to change the date/time. Can i use these directives to achive the same?

Comment: @SagarMody, This is only a datepicker, which won't allow you to pick the time. WIth this component you can select only the date, but not the time.

Comment: @Rajeshwar what about use your plugin but not in a windows modal or a pop-up? This is possible?

Comment: @Rajeshwar And another question, is possible mark "special dates" with some CSS class, just like events?

Comment: @JabelMárquez, marking a date cell with special css is possible if we make some changes in the source code. It will be something similar to disabled dates feature. But for events instead of applying disabled css, we can apply some other css as per the need. But with the existing code base, that is not possible. The source code can be modified to get these features.